# Read from single line where file contains multiple lines

Tags: c#, text

I want to read from a single line with this code:

```
            var data = File
        .ReadLines("itemdata.txt")
        .SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))
        .Select(x => x.Split('='))
        .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
        .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
```

from a text file that contains multiple lines with same text. Example: etcitem=armor is in first line and etcitem=weapon  in second line and want to read just from a single one. The resoult should be from first line : `textsearch.Text = data["etcitem"];` How is posbile? 
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe ToLookup would be better - I'm assuming you're getting an error creating the dictionary due to non-unique keys. Although I'm not sure quite what you  mean by 'read just from a single one'.

Comment: @Baldrick yes indeed i get that error. Can you show in my source?

Comment: Do you want to get just one of the results back where there are 2? Or do you want to be able to get them all back?

Comment: @Baldrick just one by line becaouse i made to search it that result from other text from that line that in other is not show.

Comment: I would suggest replacing 'ToDictionary' with 'ToLookup'. Lookup allows multiple values for each key. Then when you use the look up, you can do a string.Join to concatenate the results for that key - so you'd get back both armor and weapon, joined in a manner of your choice, on a single line.

Comment: @Baldrick is not working i tryed with textBox1.Text = data["etcitem"]; and not work.

Comment: It won't work with that. You'll have to do something like textBox1.Text = string.Join(",", data["etcitem"]);

Comment: @Baldrick works but it returns from all lines. I want only from one.

Comment: Which one? If you want just the first one, then try textBox1.Text = data["etcitem"].FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @Baldrick I want to return value from the line wich contais a specified text. Example: `item_begin 2334 etcitem=weapon` is first line and `item_begin 2335 etcitem=armor` is second. An want the etcitem value from second by value 2335.

Comment: You have accepted an answer now - glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select just the first line with .Take() as follows:

```
var data = File
    .ReadLines("itemdata.txt")
    .Where(x => x.Contains("5624"))
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
```

You can also use .Skip() if you need to skip any lines.

Comment: This takes only first line but if i use Skip it lands to a specified line and note the one i search with a specified text. Here is example:item_begin weapon 5623 etcitem=armoris first line and second is item_begin weapon 5624 etcitem=weapon. And i search by 5624

Comment: I do not completely follow you, but if you need to search for a particular line you can use a .Select(x => x.Contains(" 5624 ")) between .ReadLines() and .Take().

Comment: Can you put it in your code? Because by returns error. And yesy that is the ideea to search at a particular line.

Comment: Something like this:

    var data = File
    .ReadLines("itemdata.txt")
    .Select(x => x.Contains(" 5624 "))
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);

Comment: this part is not working anymore in your code `SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))`. Returns error.

Comment: Replaced .Select by .Where